# Usage of "bubble wand" vs "bubble blower"

Tags: word-usage

I've seen both the term "bubble wand" and "bubble blower" refer to the same thing in online translation dictionaries — a toy with a closed circle that one can blow bubbles through.

Do these terms have the exact same meaning? Are there regions where one term is used more often than the other?

Comment: I would have thought a "bubble blower" suggests a human (or perhaps a fan) blowing, while a "bubble wand" can be waved or held in the wind to create a bubble

Comment: Can you give some context for these? Do you have a quote for both? (edit and add)

Comment: "Bubble wand" is fairly precise, but "bubble blower" seems very vague with a wide range of uses.

Comment: [*blow through the **wand** to produce bubbles*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22blow+through+the+wand+to+produce%22) OR [*blow through the **hoop** to create the bubbles*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22blow+through+the+hoop+to+create%22)

Comment: @Mitch I added my interpretation of the definition that I've read online in a couple of places. I don't see much of a use for an example, since I assume both terms can be used the same way – e.g. "I took a bubble wand / bubble blower, dipped it in soapy water, and waved it around to get a beautiful assortment of short-lasting bubbles."

Comment: And as for context, up until recently, I have only been aware of the term "bubble wand". I recently noticed taht the online Czech-English dictionary I sometimes use only provides "bubble blower" as the translation for the equivalent Czech word. I then saw this same term was used on Wiktionary and even a Google search yielded a comparable number of results for "bubble blower" as for "bubble wand".

Comment: Huh. Never in my life has it occurred to me that the thing you blow bubbles through using soapy water actually has a name. I’ve owned several of them in my childhood, but I don’t think the need to name it ever arose.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A **bubble wand** is a stick with at least one circle (or other closed shape with a hole in the middle) attached to it. Bubbles are created by dipping it in soap and either blowing on it or waving it through the air. For example, from [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B093BKFSTX):

[image: bubble wands, some with one circle, others with lots of shapes and designs]

A **bubble blower** is a machine that blows bubbles (though it could also refer to a person who's blowing bubbles with a wand). You pour in bubble soap somewhere, and I guess some sort of fan blows bubbles out of a part that's essentially a bubble wand. Most of these seem to be powered by either batteries or by plugging in directly, though I would also use the term to refer to a similar device that's powered manually (e.g., by turning a crank or pushing a lever). Again, from [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B072L6MNX1):

[image: dolphin machine]

Comment: I think you're right, but then what's going on [here](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bubble_blower)?

Comment: @Heartspring Wiktionary? Please.

Comment: I'd call that fish/dolphin thing a "bubble machine" or "bubble maker" (and the Amazon listing seems to use the latter term). There are also "bubble guns" which are shaped like guns but have a similar function. You might differentiate devices by shape; by whether they have a motor, depend on turning a handle/crank/piston, or have to be waved about; whether they produce bubbles continuously; size; amount of bubbles produced; and whether they're aimed at children or adults (I've seen more professional versions used at live events). I don't think there's a definitive answer though.

Comment: @Laurel♦ Could you provide some trustworthy sources to back these definitions up?

Comment: @StuartF Sure, I'd also call those bubble machines. But that's not the point. OP asked if Wand and Blower are the same, Well, no, since when we hear "bubble blower" we think "oh, you probably mean a bubble machine".

Answer (score 1):

Let's not forget the **bubble pipe**, which IMO falls into the bubble blower category, since it holds the bubble solution as opposed to the "dip-stick" wands.

[image]

> A **bubble pipe** is a toy shaped like a tobacco pipe, intended to be used for blowing soap bubbles.
> [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_pipe)